# Display list of items in xceed datagrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed

I have a collection of items that contains another list of items.
Example classes:

```
public class Item1
{
    public int Id {get; set;}  
    public List <Item2> Items2 {get; set;}
}  
public class Item2
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

[I need to make table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TThn1.png)

I tried to display all `Item2` objects and use `CellSpanningDirection`. But if `Items2.Count = 0` I still have to display `Item1`.
So It is important that `ItemsSource` was `Item1`.
Also I tried add another datagrid in cell but it does not work.

```
<xcdg:Column>
    <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}">
                <xcdg:Column FieldName="Id">
                </xcdg:Column>
            </xcdg:DataGridControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
</xcdg:Column>
```

Please help create a table:)